# How implementation is hidden in rust?

Tags: rust

In C, a compiled library and its header file can be shared to be used along with another binary, enabling others to use but prevent from knowing the implementation.

In rust, I see the signature and implementation are in the same .rs file, so how the implementation can be hidden?

Comment: "enabling others to use but prevent from knowing the implementation" - that's quite the misbelief there.

Comment: "Distribute a library without the implementation" is a very old-fashioned perspective. C is basically the only language in mainstream use today that still does it. Java libraries are easily-parsed JAR files, Haskell just includes source like Rust does, most dynamic languages distribute libraries as pure source.

Comment: .NET languages also include quite a lot of information about implementation in their "compiled" (that word is quite overloaded in Computer Science) assemblies.

Comment: Just use a `mod`ule and don't worry about it.